Malaysia visa for Indian travelling from Bali. Immigration rules
I am an Indian national and travelling from Bali to India. I have a 9 hours layover in Kuala Lumpur.
Its a self-transfer and I would certainly need to recollect my luggage and do the immigration.
Currently the visa entry is free for Indians, however there is some kind of form that needs to be filled before entering Malaysia from India.
I am wondering, would the same form needs to be filled while travelling from Bali and does the visa-free apply here also? Would there be any hassle in doing the immigration?
Thanks

In general, visa requirements and exemptions depend on your citizenship rather than on the country from which you are traveling.  Have you done any research?  What did you find?  People often write "travelers from India" when they mean "travelers who are citizens of India."

Hints: IATA Travel Centre and Traveldoc.
